# R Shiny Dashboard - Need to overwrite default CSS on TabBox

Tags: css, r, twitter-bootstrap, shiny, shinydashboard

When I create a *tabBox* in *R* the default bootstrap tag that is generated is `col-sm-6`. I am trying to make the Bootstrap UI stack for Ipads and smaller so I really need the *div* tag to say `col-lg-6`. How can I overwrite the default *CSS* to have the `col-sm-6` grid section behave like a `col-lg-6`?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to tweak the css as follows:

```
@media screen and (max-device-width: 1024px){
   .col-sm-6 {
             min-width:100%;
              } }
```